# Is there any evidence that phytic acid in oats can be dangerous?

Tags: nutrition

I heard a lot of times that eating oats almost daily can be dangerous because of it. Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phytic_acid

Comment: Why? Phytic acid seems fine: http://www.phytochemicals.info/phytochemicals/phytic-acid.php

Comment: @JJosaur Wikipedia says it can bind iron, zinc and other minerals, preventing it from absorbtion.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phytic_acid

Comment: This article might help : https://authoritynutrition.com/phytic-acid-101/

Answer (score 4):

Although phytic acid has some anti-nutrient properties, the issue in the western world is not undernutrition but over nutrition!

And there is some suggestive evidence that phytates may have a role to play in anti-cancer activity in the large bowel.

> The authors have found that phytic acid is a potent inhibitor of iron-mediated generation of the hazardous oxidant, hydroxyl radical. Herein, the authors propose that inhibition of intracolonic hydroxyl radical generation, via the chelation of reactive iron by phytic acid, may help explain the suppression of colonic carcinogenesis and other inflammatory bowel diseases by diets rich in phytic acid.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2990653

Comment: 'the issue in the western world is not undernutrition but over nutrition' - wait, what. What is that supposed to mean? Eating too many calories has nothing to do with eating too many nutrients. In fact, I'd say the problem is too many calories combined with too few nutrients. Phytic acid for example reduces zinc absorption which is especially relevant to plant-based eaters.